# Accept number as string in request body?

Tags: json, api, rest, vert.x

I have an API spec that defines a parameter `account_id` as a `string` in the request body.

Say a request comes in with a `number` or even `boolean` for that field. Something like:

```
"account_id": 1234567890
```

or

```
"account_id": true
```

The deserializer I'm using, Vert.x's `Json.decodeValue`, automatically converts these types to `string` (but it doesn't provide an option for strict type checking).

**Question:**

What the best practice in this scenario? Should I be strict about the spec and reject the request? Or let `number` and `boolean` be silently converted to `string`?

Answer (score 0):

That's a very broad question, not directly related to Vert.x.

TL;DR - let it be converted to String, then parse it again in your business layer doing the necessary validations.

I would say it really depends on the purpose of your API. Why `account_id` is a string? Is it because you planned to use UUIDs or some other non-numeric identifier in the future?

Anyway, it seems that this is a business concern. So, receive `account_id` as a String, then if needed, parse it as an Integer and return relevant error. In the future, in case you'd also receive other types of identifiers, you can add another validation, returning same type of error.

Answer (score 0):

vert.x's `Json` class is a wrapper around Jackson's `ObjectMapper` which is a public static field.

That means you can configure it any way you like:

```
Json.mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_NULL_FOR_PRIMITIVES, false);
```